# Convert Object to Inherited Object

Tags: c#

I am working on a program that is similar to Netflix and involves movies.

I have a Movie Object/class from an API that my program uses. I made a inherited class of that Object like so.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using TMDbLib.Objects.Movies;
namespace Movie_Management.DATA
{
    class MyMovie: TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie
    {
        public string Path { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Here is the code where I get the Movie object from the API I use.

```
        TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie movie = new TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie();
        movie = MovieProcesses.loadTMDbLib(justMovieName);
        MyMovie myMovie = (MyMovie)movie;
        myMovie.Path = path;

        Cacher cache = new Cacher();
        cache.CacheVideo(myMovie);
```

I attempt to cast the TMDbLib Movie to the MyMovie object. But it does not work. What am I supposed to do in this situation?

```
{"Unable to cast object of type 'TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie' to type 'Movie_Management.DATA.MyMovie'."}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't cast "backwards" in inheritance hierarchies. You can only go from Movie to MyMovie, not the other way around.

If you want to add extra stuff to an existing Movie object, add a constructor to MyMovie that takes a Movie object as a parameter and copy the member variables across manually.

Comment: Well, you can cast "backwards" which is called downcasting. That's why OP has a runtime error — he can cast but the casting is wrong.

Comment: @Illuminati, you can cast `Movie` to `MyMovie` iff the reference of type `Movie` points to either `MyMovie` object or its descendant(which you don't have).

Answer (score 0):

```
    TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie movie = new MyMovie();
    movie = MovieProcesses.loadTMDbLib(justMovieName);
    MyMovie myMovie = movie as MyMovie;
    myMovie.Path = path;

    Cacher cache = new Cacher();
    cache.CacheVideo(myMovie);
```

Hope these code help

Comment: Object reference not set to an instance of an object. For myMovie.Path = path;

Comment: please be aware of 'TMDbLib.Objects.Movies.Movie movie = new MyMovie();'